# Enforce package separation (avoid imports from specific modules)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a python app that contains the following root folders:

```
 +---FrontEnd 
 +---BackEnd
 +---Common
```

FrontEnd and BackEnd import from Common but Common should not import from the former. I'd like to enforce this rule programatically so my team (especially new team members) do not accidentally import FrontEnd or BackEnd into Common.

I heard import hooks could help here but I haven't found much info on this. My first attempt didn't go so well either:

**`Common.__init__.py`**

```
class NoForeignDependencies(object):

    PATH_TRIGGERS = ['FrontEnd', 'BackEnd']

    def __init__(self, path_entry):
        if path_entry not in self.PATH_TRIGGERS:
            raise ImportError()

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        print 'Import not allowed for this module'
        return None

sys.path_hooks.append(NoForeignDependencies)
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: It is absolutely necessary to do it in development time? We have these  kind of checks in a git pre-commit hook, so you can do such imports for testing or playing, and are only rejected if tried to commit. But it is not necessary to push to the CI system to let the tests fail, if you know that logic in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about making those three into separate packages, and then have automatically running unit tests for each package using Jenkins for example, where only a limited number of people have access to Jenkins? This way if someone goes and adds an import of FrontEnd in Common, Common tests would fail on Jenkins, because FrontEnd has not been installed in the Common environment that Jenkins uses to run Common tests.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was hoping there was an programmatic way to accomplish this (ideally with the ability to disable it upon deployment)